# Build an arm64v8 docker on CircleCI

Tags: circleci, arm64, dockerhub, nvidia-jetson-nano

I want to build on `CircleCi` [ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/Documentation) packages to use on `Nvidia Jetson Nano`.
Today I use Upboard which has amd64 arch, so it all been clear.
I used a docker from dockerhub, I all worked well.
Today I cannot find a way to build an arm64v8( the Jetson arch) on docker hub.
When I import `FROM` an `arm64` image it fails because the arch doesn't suit (I guess the docker is an amd64 docker).

Do you know a way to create an `arm64` docker on docker hub to use it on `CircleCI`? (`ROS` compitible one would be great).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build arm64 docker image with CircleCI (then you can push it to dockerhub), there two solutions:

1/Use CircleCI machine executor and install QEMU to build multi-arch image. (or only linux/arm64 if you want)

https://namiops.medium.com/build-a-multi-arch-docker-image-with-circleci-for-amd64-arm64-risc64-3ad0537a1f28

Github: https://github.com/namiops/circleci-multiarch

2/Use CircleCI arm machine executor, which simpiler and faster to build arm64 image.

https://namiops.medium.com/golang-arm64-docker-image-with-circleci-arm-machine-8bebf2151b92

Github: https://github.com/namiops/circleci-arm